# psql role doesn't exist for remote host, does locally

Tags: ldap, authentication, postgresql

I have a local psql server configured to use ldap for all but `postgres` accounts. But ldap isn't used on `local` where psql has no problem with the role, and fails to find the role using `host`, where ldap is used.

Is the role not found because of a pg_hba.conf problem or an issue with granting extra permissions? Something else?

#### socket

```
psql lncddb useraccnt 
# psql (11.2 (Debian 11.2-2), server 10.4 (Debian 10.4-2))
# login without password prompt, 'useraccnt' is also system account (in /etc/passwd)
```

#### local

```
psql -h localhost lncddb useraccnt 
# Password for user useraccnt: fake
```

#### remote

```
psql -h 10.145.64.121 lncddb useraccnt -p 5433
# Password for user useraccnt: ldappass
```

> psql: FATAL:  role "useraccnt" does not exist

or if wrong password is given

> psql: FATAL:  LDAP authentication failed for user "useraccnt"
>
> FATAL:  LDAP authentication failed for user "useraccnt"

---

`pg_hba`

```
# postgres is special
local   all             postgres                           peer
host    all             postgres   0.0.0.0/0               md5
# everyone else should go through ldap
local   all             all                                     ldap ldapserver=a.b.net ldapsuffix="@place.edu"  ldapport=389
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               ldap ldapserver=a.b.net ldapsuffix="@place.edu"  ldapport=389
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ldap ldapserver=a.b.net ldapsuffix="@place.edu"  ldapport=389
```

foranw created like

```
create role useraccnt with LOGIN REPLICATION password 'fake';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE lncddb TO useraccnt;
```

the roles for `lncddb` are

```
 psql lncddb postgres -c '\l lncddb'
                                List of databases
  Name  |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
--------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 lncddb | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres         +
        |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres+
        |          |          |             |             | useraccnt=CTc/postgres
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

specify ports and the psql header (`psql (11.2 (Debian 11.2-2), server 10.4 (Debian 10.4-2))`) should have tipped me off. I'm was configuring the wrong server.

```
systemctl |grep postgres
  postgresql.service            loaded active     exited    PostgreSQL RDBMS                                                                                   
  postgresql@10-main.service    loaded active     running   PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main                                                                         
  postgresql@11-main.service    loaded active     running   PostgreSQL Cluster 11-main                                                                         
  system-postgresql.slice       loaded active     active    system-postgresql.slice
```